# Macbook internet speed slowing down

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2017(Mojave 10.14.6). For some kind of reason the internet speed keeps slowing down from 50 Mbit to somewhere between 25-35 Mbit. I'm connecting through WiFi, but have verified that the WiFi speed isn't the problem. I can also confirm with my much older iMac I can hit the 50 Mbit through WiFi every time.

I checked to see if any application is constantly pulling data through the Activity Monitor, but not seeing anything strange.

I also followed the steps over here: [OSXDAILY](https://osxdaily.com/2016/09/22/fix-wi-fi-problems-macos-sierra/) but without luck.

Usually a restart helps restoring the speed but within 1 or 2 days it's down again. I do let the macbook sleep.

Any clue or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!